# Capturing Ctrl+C, Ctr+V in Infragistics UltraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, infragistics

I've been seeing this weird behavior where any keyboard combinations with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are being ignored. Ignore the way it's broken out (just structured for testing).

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
{
    if (e.Control)
    {
        var test = "testing";
    }
}
```

If I breakpoint on the first if statement, any keypress will hit it. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> immediately triggers, so I went one layer deeper and breakpointed `if (e.Control)`. This should be hit any time the letter C is involved (whether being pressed on its own or modified with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>). Pressing <kbd>C</kbd>triggers it. Pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not. The kicker is pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> DOES TRIGGER IT. So I'm guessing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> must be being consumed by something else specifically?

I've dug through the code and don't see that happening anywhere else. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I think CTRL+C is not CTRL key then C key, it has its own key value.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;//Get event
if (!e.ctrlKey) return;

var code = e.which || e.keyCode;//Get key code
switch (code) {
    case 67: //Block Ctrl+C
    case 65: //Block Ctrl+A
    case 88: //Block Ctrl+X
    case 73: //Block Ctrl+I
    case 80: //Block Ctrl+P
    //  case 86: //Block Ctrl+V
    case 85: //Block Ctrl+U
    case 83: //Block Ctrl+S
    case 87: //Block Ctrl+W -- Not work in Chrome and new Firefox
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        break;
}
```

};

Above code is working good !! I don't know it is exactly your question's answer but You can get an idea from here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a `ToolBar`, `ToolStrip` or `Context` menu on form with shortcuts for those key combinations, so it's eating the messages and they never get to the `UltraGrid`.